# ArcPad Jscript ThisEvent.Object, autofill form with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, events, arcpad

I have a script that I'm trying to use to autofill the controls of an ArcPad form with controls on multiple pages.  The 'autofill()' function is referenced in the form's onload event and I would like to avoid opening each page individually.  The following code works well for the first page but the second page does not autofill.  Am I referencing the second page incorrectly?  I have a third page to add as well.  The myentries[] is an array that references specific values for each control (which are comboboxes).

Code:

```
function autofill(){
var pages, datepage, controls1, notespage, controls2;

datepage=ThisEvent.Object.Pages("date");
controls1=datepage.Controls;
controls1.Item("cboemp").ListIndex=myentries[0];
controls1.Item("cboaction").ListIndex=myentries[1];

notespage=ThisEvent.Object.Pages("notes");
controls2=notespage.Controls;
controls2.Item("cbolarvae").ListIndex=myentries[2];
controls2.Item("cbopupae").ListIndex=myentries[3];
controls2.Item("cboadults").ListIndex=myentries[4];
}
```